# Setting the label next to a textbos without using tables HTML\CSS

Tags: forms, html, text, textbox, label

I am doing a website for my personal use.  I need some assistant on how to set a text-box next to a label without using tables. They are in their own division tags

```
<div id="outter">

        <div class="1">
       Fill out and submit the form below and we will contact you a.s.a.p.
        </div>

        <div class="2">
       <label> Name: </label>
        </div>
           <div class="2">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="3" >
        </div>
</div>
```

trying to get this:

```
[input box 1]   label 1
[input box 2]   label 2
```

here is the link for better details

http://homework.genesee.edu/~dmead1/forms/table.html

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Solution Of Your Problem

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="login">     
<legend>Fill out and submit the form below and we will contact you a.s.a.p. </legend>

<div><label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name"></div>

</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
 fieldset div {
  margin:0.3em 0;
  clear:both;
 }
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eSr3J/)